# Firebase doesn't deploy my function, says it isn't a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is my function, getAccountType

```
import { firebaseAdmin } from './index';

export const getAccountType = async (data: any, context: any) => {
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    try{
        const snapshot = await firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).get();
        if(snapshot.exists){
            const data = snapshot.data() as { accountType : 'youth' | 'prof', firstName : string, isProfileComplete : boolean};
            return data;
        }
        else{
            return { message : "User does not exist"};
        };
    } catch(e){
        return { message : `Failed to get user data ${e}` };
    };
};
```

And this is my index.ts file

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { helloWorld } from "./helloWorld";
import { getAccountType } from "./getAccountType";


export const firebaseAdmin = admin.initializeApp();
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onCall(helloWorld)
exports.getAccountType = functions.https.onCall(getAccountType)
```

And here is the error I receive

```
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers. Please ensure that index.js only exports cloud functions.
```

The HelloWorld function deploys just fine, but for some reason firebase thinks getAccountType is not a cloud function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to deploy your code on Firebase Cloud Functions by making some adjustments. The error is saying that you can only export functions. You cannot export declarations such as `const`.

To fix the error, remove `firebaseAdmin` on **index.ts**.

**index.ts**

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { getAccountType } from "./getAccountType";

exports.getAccountType = functions.https.onCall(getAccountType)
```

**getAccountType.ts**

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

export const getAccountType = async (data: any, context: any) => {
    // Your code logic
    ...
};
```